# from markers to polylines. maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

i have an array o markers and i want to create polylines according their title `markers[i].title` . My brain can't think of a decent peace of code right now, so little help would be useful...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm afraid I don't understand your question. How do you determine what polyline to show based on the title? Does the title contain a description of a polyline?

Answer (score 1):

You want likely a polyline based on the coordinates (LatLng) of the markers. Here is a template code:

```
function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.0, 10.0),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var points = [     
        new google.maps.LatLng(39.0, -3.0),     
        new google.maps.LatLng(52.1, 12.1),     
        new google.maps.LatLng(40.2, 32.7)  
    ]; 
    var markers = [];
    var path = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: points[i]});
        markers.push(marker);
        path.push(marker.position);
    }
    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({     
        path: path,     
        strokeColor: "#FF0000"
    });    
    polyline.setMap(map);  
}
```

Comment: @drou: was this any useful for you?

Comment: thnx for answering but this is the general way of creating a polyline, i asked for a polyline for each marker title (i might have 100 markers with the same title). if there are two different titles there will be two different polylines.